# string,list pair in a row in data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dictionary, dataframe

I have a data frame as follows:

```
date = "2000"
values = c("a","b","d")
df <- data.frame(date=date,values= values)
df
  date values
1 2000      a
2 2000      b
3 2000      d
```

Actually i have thousands of values in `values` field. So instead of printing as separate rows i want to make a data frame contains one row that contains all information.ie, something like :

```
1 2000    a,b,d
```

Is this possible in R, something like `map<String,arrayList(String)>` in java?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if you tell us what you intend to do with resultant data.

Comment: If you want `values` as a `list` then do: `aggregate(values ~ date, df, list)`

Comment: by this command i am getting the row numbers only.
date  values
1 2000 1, 2, 3
Actually i need the data of that row numbers.

Comment: @DinoopNair, that's because `values` is `factor`. Just change it to `character` with `as.character` (as Ananda's solution has shown).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not clear what you want, but here's some code with `aggregate` to get you started:

```
> df$values <- as.character(df$values)
> # A `list` of the values
> (da1 <- aggregate(values ~ date, df, I, simplify=FALSE))
  date  values
1 2000 a, b, d
> str(da1)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date  : Factor w/ 1 level "2000": 1
 $ values:List of 1
  ..$ 0:Class 'AsIs'  chr [1:3] "a" "b" "d"

> # All the values collapsed into one string
> (da2 <- aggregate(values ~ date, df, paste, collapse = ", ", simplify=FALSE))
  date  values
1 2000 a, b, d
> str(da2)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date  : Factor w/ 1 level "2000": 1
 $ values:List of 1
  ..$ 0: chr "a, b, d"
```

I've shown the `str`ucture so you can see the difference between the two examples here.

---

If I understand your comment below correctly, you might also be interested in this:

```
> date = "2000"
> values = c("a", "b", "d")
> (temp <- data.frame(date, values = I(list(values))))
  date  values
1 2000 a, b, d
> str(temp)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ date  : Factor w/ 1 level "2000": 1
 $ values:List of 1
  ..$ : chr  "a" "b" "d"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"
```

In other words, if you want to have a `list` as a column item when creating a `data.frame` you must use the `I` function.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, should we retag? :)

Comment: The fact that you are alone in the aggregation tag is that you are the only one using it ;)

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I think both title and tags needs to be re-'d.

Comment: @AnandaMahto: it is good and working perfectly. can we store values as list in the first time itself? ie, without creating df?

Comment: @DinoopNair, not sure if I understand correctly, but see my update.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
df <- structure(list(date = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L), values = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", 
"b", "d"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("date", "values"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

This gives you what you propose as output to get all the information in one row, but all the values are in one cell:

```
library(plyr)

df2 <- ddply(df,.(date),summarize,values=as.list(paste(values,collapse=",")))
```

You can also transform the data to wide format so each value is a new variable:

```
library(reshape2)

df$id <- seq_along(df)
dfwide <- reshape(df, idvar = c("date"),timevar = "id", direction = "wide")
```

Comment: Maybe you can also provide a solution that gives a `list` back in addition to `paste`ing them together? I'd be happy to up-vote.

Comment: that's different from what I meant, but it's okay :) (+1).

Answer (score 2):

This will give you a list of values per year:

```
tapply(df$values,df$date,I)
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: The `as.data.frame` seems to have no effect. For your solution, an alternative is `split(df$values, df$date)`

Comment: @Arun Omitting it produces another result. Perhaps `I` is more appropriate though, thanks for noticing.